# Show $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $dr^2 + \sinh^2r d \theta^2$ is isometric to the Poincare disc with $g = \frac{4(dx^2 + dy^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}$

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

How do I show $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $dr^2 + \sinh^2r d \theta^2$ is isometric to the Poincare disc with $g = \frac{4(dx^2 + dy^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}$?

I tried converting to polar coordinates, so that $x = r \cos{\theta}$ and $y = r\sin{\theta}$. Then $$g = \frac{4}{(1-r^2)^2} (dr^2 + r^2 d{\theta}^2). $$

I don't really know where to go from here. I saw somewhere that $$\sinh^2{r} = \frac{4r^2}{(1-r^2)^2},$$ but I don't know how to get to that. Even if I did, that would only take care of the second term, but $dr^2$ would still have that additional factor in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
    \newcommand{\sech}{\mathop{\rm sech}\nolimits}
    \newcommand{\csch}{\mathop{\rm csch}\nolimits}
  $

Define a map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to D$ by $x=\tanh{(r/2)}\cos{\theta}$, $y=\tanh{(r/2)}\sin{\theta}$. To compute the new metric, we use
$$ g(x)_{ij} = g(y)_{kl} \frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial y^l}{\partial x^j} ,$$
the transformation law for a covariant tensor (in particular, we have to start with the metric on $D$ and pull back to the metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$). In this case,
$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{2}\sech^2{(r/2)}\cos{\theta}, \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} = \frac{1}{2}\sech^2{(r/2)}\sin{\theta} \\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} = -\tanh{(r/2)}\sin{\theta} \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} = \tanh{(r/2)}\cos{\theta}, $$
and the metric on $D$, written in the new coordinates, is
$$ \frac{4}{\sech^4{(r/2)}}\delta_{kl} $$
so in matrix notation,
$$ g_{rr} = \frac{4}{\sech^4{(r/2)}}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2}\sech^2{(r/2)}\cos{\theta} \\ \frac{1}{2}\sech^2{(r/2)}\sin{\theta} \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \sech^2{(r/2)}\cos{\theta} \\ \frac{1}{2}\sech^2{(r/2)}\sin{\theta} \end{pmatrix} = \dots = 1, $$
and by the same process,
$$ g_{r\theta}=g_{\theta r}=0, \quad g_{\theta\theta} = \sinh^2{r}, $$
as required.

Comment: How did you get $g_{\theta \theta} = \sinh^2{r}$? What did you plug in as the vector coordinates for the argument for the quadratic form?

Comment: Actually, I just used your map, found $dx$ and $dy$, and then showed the expression for $g$ reduces to $dr^2 + \sinh^2{r} d\theta^2$. Also, I think you should've plugged in $\frac{1}{2}\sech^2{(r/2)}\sin{\theta}$ as the second coordinate in your calculation of $g_{rr}$, right?.

Comment: Oh rats, got my vectors muddled. They should be $\partial (x,y)/\partial r$, of course... then it actually works. The others are found using $\partial (x,y)/\partial \theta$ (for $g_{\theta\theta}$, and $\partial (x,y)/\partial r$ one side and $\partial (x,y)/\partial \theta$ on the other side (for $g_{r\theta}$ and $g_{\theta r}$).

Comment: Your idea does also work. It's a question of how you want to do the algebra, really.